# Google cloud billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an evaluation account set up on google app engine. I have a simple java-application (rest endpoint basically) and a mysql database.

Neither is used at all if I don't make requests there (no background processes eg.). And the requests and data is miniscule, just a couple of tables and rows. The application is not used at all most of the time.

So I was wondering why the mysql console for example shows about 2 requests/second constantly (in the google dashboard and in the mysql console if you follow the request from the "status" command).

So to recap, I have an application that isn't used deployed, and a mysql database. The bill for a month looks like this:

DB standard Intel N1 1 VCPU running in EUROPEWEST3 (with 30% promotional discount): 672 Hours - 44.08eur

Storage PD SSD for DB in Frankfurt: 10 Gibibyte months - 1.65eur

How can I find out what is eating these resources? Mysql seems to be the culprit here. 10Gb of data usage for mysql (which has maybe received 1000 real queries for rows containing maybe 100 characters of data).

Edit: I now notice that the hours and Gb-months are actually the timeperiod, not the "usage" (even though it says "usage" on the bill).

So maybe the question is, is google really this expensive? 50eur/month for a database.

Comment: If you leave the server running, you pay. By the hour. If you use storage you pay by the second.  The CPU utilisation does not come into it. You are at least getting a discount. These charges can run into thousands for the careless. You should be able to get .csv repotrs in  a storage bucket.

Comment: Ok, I figured out as much (now). Maybe I'll start looking at some private server, should be cheaper (as I won't be needing massive scaling, which probably would cost massively also...). The price really surprised me (this is an evaluation account with 300 eur in credits so I don't have to pay anything).

Answer (score 1):

With Google Cloud SQL, you pay for instance compute time, instance storage, and storage snapshots. I have a DB standard N1 1 that runs 50 USD a month compute plus about 10 USD storage. I also have a DB standard N1 2 that runs exactly double that a month.

You storage is the size of the disk, 10GB SSD minimum. You pay for that 10GB no matter how much of that you use.

As a point of comparison, these costs are nearly identical to what you'd pay for the managed RDS service on AWS.

In a trial period, I would consider using a db-g1 or db-f1, and only upgrade them when your stats show you that you need to.